# What is a special sign of predestination? (Catholic)

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, predestination, grace, rosary

One of the promises given by Mary to the people who pray the rosary is

> Devotion to my Rosary is a special sign of predestination.

[Reference](http://www.onepeterfive.com/why-you-should-pray-the-rosary-daily-15-reasons-straight-from-our-lady/)

I read many things on predestination and can't really find a proper description of what it means in regards to this message.

It's something that highlights we were predestined by God. We were predestined to receive his grace but not predestined, as Calvinists believe, to obtain his salvation after we die.

Is there any explanation what it means to obtain a special sign of predestination according to the Catholic Church?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part II, §4 "Synthesis," ch. IV "On the Certainly of Predestination," § "Signs of Predestination" of [Fr. Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reginald_Garrigou-Lagrange)'s [*Predestination: The Meaning of Predestination in Scripture and the Church*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/3045) says:

> **Signs of Predestination**
>
> Can we be certain in this life that we are predestined? In answer to this question the Council of Trent says: "No one, so long as he is in this mortal life, ought so far to presume as regards the secret mystery of divine predestination as to determine for certain that he is assuredly in the number of the predestinate; as if it were true that he who is justified either cannot sin any more, or, if he do sin, that he ought to promise himself an assured repentance. For, except by special revelation, it cannot be known whom God hath chosen unto Himself."<sup>14</sup> The reason for this is because, without a special revelation, we cannot know for certain what depends solely upon God's free will. Not one of the just, unless it is specially revealed, knows whether he will persevere in the performance of good works and in prayer. We shall be, says St. Paul, "heirs indeed of God and joint heirs with Christ; yet so, if we suffer [perseveringly] with Him, that we may be also glorified with Him."<sup>15</sup>
>
> Are there, however, any signs of predestination such as to give one a sort of moral certainty of perseverance? The Fathers, especially John Chrysostom, Augustine, Gregory the Great, Bernard, and Anselm, according to certain statements of Holy Scripture, pointed out several signs of predestination often enumerated by the theologians as follows:
>
> 1. a good life;
> 2. the testimony of a conscience that is free from serious sins and prepared rather to die than offend God grievously;
> 3. patience in adversities endured for the love of God;
> 4. readiness to hear the word of God;
> 5. compassion for the poor;
> 6. love of one's enemies;
> 7. humility;
> 8. a special devotion to the Blessed Virgin whom we ask every day to pray for us at the hour of our death.
>
> Among these signs, certain ones, such as Christian patience in adversity, are proof that the inequality of natural conditions is at times more than compensated by divine grace. This is borne out by the beatitudes as recorded in the Gospel: "Blessed are the poor in spirit, the meek, they that mourn, they that hunger and thirst after justice, the merciful, the clean of heart, the peacemakers, they that suffer persecution for justice' sake: for theirs is the kingdom of heaven."<sup>16</sup> These are the predestined. St. Thomas points out especially in his teaching that to bear patiently a heavy cross and for a long time is a sign of predestination.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Notes
> 14. [Denz., no. 8](http://patristica.net/denzinger/#n800)05 [=[Council of Trent session 6, ch. 11](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.i.i.iv.html#v.i.i.iv-p58.6)]; cf. [no. 8](http://patristica.net/denzinger/#n800)26 [=[Council of Trent session 6, canon 16](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.i.i.iv.html#v.i.i.iv-p89.36)].
> 15. [Rom. 8: 17](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=52&ch=8&l=17#x).
> 16. [Matt. 5: 3](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=5&l=3#x)–10.</sup>

Comment: this also doesn't fully answer my question but I will mark it as the right answers as it carries some hints to it. Thanks

Comment: @Grasper Were you looking for something addressing Catholic vs. Calvinist conceptions of predestination? If so, see [my answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/47430/1787) to the question "[How does the Roman Catholic Church interpret predestination?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/47426/1787)."

Answer (score 1):

*Devotion to the Mother of Jesus through the rosary* **"is"** the great sign of predestination! We can not look for a tangible great sign here on earth since devotion to the rosary is the great sign in itself of our salvation.

> Whoever recites my Rosary devoutly, reflecting on the mysteries, shall never be overwhelmed by misfortune. He will not experience the anger of God nor will he perish by an unprovided death. The sinner will be converted; the just will persevere in grace and merit eternal life. - [15 Promises of the Rosary](https://www.catholicity.com/prayer/promises.html)

A priest friend of mine once said about a non-Catholic praying the rosary daily that it in itself was a sign that she would eventually become a Catholic. She did.

> One of the greatest means of salvation is devotion to the Most Blessed Virgin Mary. The saints are unanimous in saying that, **"A devout client of Mary shall never perish."** St. Thomas Aquinas said that "many souls are now in Heaven, through the prayers of Mary, who otherwise would not be there." Mary Herself assures us in one of Her promises of the Rosary, to St. Dominic, **"Devotion of My Rosary is a great sign of predestination."** [Devotion to Mary —
> A Great Sign of Predestination](https://motherofgodlibrary.org/2019/05/18/devotion-to-mary-a-great-sign-of-predestination/)

Comment: sorry, this is not what I'm asking...