# Is it true that anyone who prays the rosary cannot be touched by Satan?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, satan, rosary

Fr. Gabrielle Amorth a famous deceased Rome Chief Exorcist who performed a record breaking 50,000 Exorcism Rite or even higher figures said the following phrase:

"Anyone who prays the rosary cannot be touch by Satan."

My little understanding on the phrase implied praying the rosary becomes a shield that Satan cannot penetrates.

I find this amazing although believable because coming from the main exorcist at Rome who experienced battling Satan and his demons in oppressed, obssessed even possessed individuals and had a well documented deliverance success.

My question is, is there a good explanation to convince Catholic members that this phrase is supported by Catholic Church Doctrine?

Comment: related: "[What is a special sign of predestination? (Catholic)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/54055/1787)," which quotes: "Devotion to my Rosary is a special sign of predestination."

Answer (score 1):

**A closer look on the phrase will lead us to special sign of predestination as given on the Fifteen Powerful Promises of all Christian who prays the Holy Rosary.**

Source: [Our Lady's 15 Promises for Praying the Rosary](https://www.ourladyswarriors.org/prayer/15promise.htm)

**Our Lady's 15 Promises for Praying the Rosary**

> Besides the Indulgences attached to the Rosary, Our Lady revealed to St. Dominic and Blessed Alan de la Roche additional benefits for those who devoutly pray the Rosary.  Additional explanation on and doctrinal connections to each promise is shown below the promises. . Note that the Rosary is the prayer (non-Liturgical) with the most published Magisterial / Papal documents expounding on its excellence. Vatican II's summary on Our Lady is contained in Lumen Gentium chapter VIII.
>
> 1. Whosoever shall faithfully serve me by the recitation of the Rosary shall receive signal graces.
>      Signal Graces are those special and unique Graces to help sanctify us in our state in life. See the remaining promises for an explanation for which these will consist. St. Louis de Montfort states emphatically that the best and fastest way to union with Our Lord is via Our Lady [True Devotion to Mary, chapter four].
> 2. I promise my special protection and the greatest graces to all those who shall recite the Rosary.
>      Our Lady is our Advocate and the channel of all God's Grace to us. Our Lady is simply highlighting that She will watch especially over us who pray the Rosary. (see Lumen Gentium chapter VIII - Our Lady #62) [a great more detail is available on this topic in True Devotion to Mary, chapter four, by St. Louis de Montfort]
> 3. The Rosary shall be a powerful armor against hell, it will destroy vice, decrease sin and defeat heresies.
>      This promise, along with the next, is simply the reminder on how fervent prayer will help us all grow in holiness by avoiding sin, especially a prayer with the excellence of the Rosary. An increase in holiness necessarily requires a reduction in sin, vice, and doctrinal errors (heresies). If only the Modernists could be convinced to pray the Rosary! (see Lumen Gentium chapter V - The Call to Holiness #42) St. Louis de Montfort states "Since Mary alone crushed all heresies, as we are told by the Church under the guidance of the Holy Spirit (Office of the Blessed Virgin Mary)..." [True Devotion to Mary #167]
> 4. It will cause good works to flourish; it will obtain for souls the abundant mercy of God; it will withdraw the hearts of men from the love of the world and its vanities, and will lift them to the desire for Eternal Things. Oh, that souls would sanctify themselves by this means.
>      This promise, along with the previous, is the positive part, that being to live in virtue. Becoming holy is not only avoiding sin, but also growing in virtue. (see Lumen Gentium chapter V - The Call to Holiness #42)
> 5. The soul which recommends itself to me by the recitation of the Rosary shall not perish.
>      Since Our Lady is our Mother and Advocate, She always assists those who call on Her implicitly by praying the Rosary. The Church reminds us of this in the Memorare prayer, "... never was it known that anyone who fled to your protection, implored your help or sought your intercession, was left unaided ..."
> 6. Whosoever shall recite the Rosary devoutly, applying himself to the consideration of its Sacred Mysteries shall never be conquered by misfortune. God will not chastise him in His justice, he shall not perish by an unprovided death; if he be just he shall remain in the grace of God, and become worthy of Eternal Life.
>      This promise highlights the magnitude of Graces that the Rosary brings to whomever prays it. One will draw down God's Mercy rather than His Justice and will have a final chance to repent (see promise #7). One will not be conquered by misfortune means that Our Lady will obtain for the person sufficient Graces to handle said misfortune (i.e. carry the Crosses allowed by God) without falling into despair. As Sacred Scripture tells us, "For my yoke is sweet and my burden light." (Matthew 11:30)
> 7. Whoever shall have a true devotion for the Rosary shall not die without the Sacraments of the Church.
>      This promise highlights the benefits of obtaining the most possible Graces at the hour of death via the Sacraments of Confession, Eucharist, and Extreme Unction (Anointing of the Sick). Being properly disposed while receiving these Sacraments near death ensures one's salvation (although perhaps with a detour through Purgatory) since a final repentance is possible.
> 8. Those who are faithful to recite the Rosary shall have during their life and at their death the Light of God and the plenitude of His Graces; at the moment of death they shall participate in the Merits of the Saints in Paradise.
>      Our Lady highlights the great quantity of Graces obtain through praying the Rosary, which assist us during life and at the moment of death. The merits of the Saints are the gift of God's rewards to those persons who responded to His Grace that they obtained during life, and so Our Lady indicates that She will provide a share of that to us at death. With this promise and #7 above, Our Lady is providing the means for the person to have a very holy death.
> 9. I shall deliver from purgatory those who have been devoted to the Rosary.
>      Should one require Purgatorial cleansing after death, Our Lady will make a special effort to obtain our release from Purgatory through Her intercession as Advocate.
> 10. The faithful children of the Rosary shall merit a high degree of Glory in Heaven.
>       This promise is a logical consequence of promises #3 and #4 since anyone who truly lives a holier life on earth will obtain a higher place in Heaven. The closer one is to God while living on earth, the close that person is to Him also in Heaven. The Catechism of the Catholic Church states "Spiritual progress tends toward ever more union with Christ." (Catechism of the Catholic Church paragraph 2014)
> 11. You shall obtain all you ask of me by recitation of the Rosary.
>       This promise emphasizes Our Lady's role as our Advocate and Mediatrix of all Graces. Of course, all requests are subject to God's Most Perfect Will. God will always grant our request if it is beneficial for our soul, and Our Lady will only intercede for us when our request is good for our salvation. (see Lumen Gentium chapter VIII - Our Lady #62)
> 12. All those who propagate the Holy Rosary shall be aided by me in their necessities.
>       If one promotes the praying of the Rosary, Our Lady emphasizes Her Maternal care for us by obtaining many Graces (i.e. spiritual necessities) and also material necessities (neither excess nor luxury), all subject to the Will of God of course.
> 13. I have obtained from my Divine Son that all the advocates of the Rosary shall have for intercessors the entire Celestial Court during their life and at the hour of death.
>       Since Our Lady is our Advocate, She brings us additional assistance during our life and at our death from all the saints in Heaven (the Communion of Saints). See paragraphs 954 through 959 in the Catechism of the Catholic Church.
> 14. All who recite the Rosary are my Sons, and brothers of my Only Son Jesus Christ.
>       Since the Rosary is a most excellent prayer focused on Jesus and His Life and activities in salvation history, it brings us closer to Our Lord and Our Lady. Doctrinally, Our Lady is our Mother and Jesus is our Eldest Brother, besides being our God. (see Lumen Gentium chapter VIII - Our Lady #62)
> 15. Devotion to my Rosary is a great sign of predestination.
>       Predestination in this context means that, by the sign which is present to a person from the action of devoutly praying the Rosary, God has pre-ordained your salvation. Absolute certainty of salvation can only be truly known if God reveals it to a person because, although we are given sufficient Grace during life, our salvation depends upon our response to said Grace. (See Summa Theologica, Question 23 for a detailed theological explanation). Said another way, if God has guaranteed a person's salvation but has not revealed it to Him, God would want that person to pray the Rosary because of all the benefits and Graces obtained. Therefore the person gets a hint by devotion to the Rosary. This is not to say that praying the Rosary guarantees salvation - by no means. In looking at promises #3 and #4 above, praying the Rosary helps one to live a holy life, which is itself a great sign that a soul is on the road to salvation. (See also paragraphs 381, 488, 600, 2782 in the Catechism of the Catholic Church.) In fact, St. Louis de Montfort says even more strongly that "an infallible and unmistakable sign by which we can distinguish a heretic, a man of false doctrine, an enemy of God, from one of God's true friends is that the hardened sinner and heretic show nothing but contempt and indifference to Our Lady..." [True Devotion to Mary, #30]

The 15 promises says it all, and biblically the Power of Mary is given by God to fulfill Her Role in Salvation of Man in Genesis3:15.

And Father Gabrielle Amorth just summarize the benefits of praying the rosary in one phrase.

> "Anyone who goes to Mary and prays the rosary cannot be touch by satan"

Fr. Amorth exclaiming this powerful statement comes deep from the heart of his experienced as Chief Exorcist in Rome for several decades and performed more than 50,000 Exorcism Rite.

As a faithful Catholic and devoted to Mary's powerful intercession one must not forget the Sacraments as the prime source of graces particularly the Holy Eucharist.

Living in the state of grace is the highest protection against satan, and by praying the rosary one is protected to resist and overcome satan snares to not lose the graces derived from the sacraments by having a powerful Mother at our side. Our Lady's blue mantle of protection is our shield.

**In closing, the 15 promises of the Holy Rosary can be verified to the numerous life of the Saints who are deeply devoted to Our Lady. Their names are in the thousands but it's worthy to mentioned three great giant Marian saints in the person of St. Alphonsus Liguori, St. Louis De Montfort and St. Maximillian Kolbe all of this saints not only exemplifies a pious life but teaches a profound doctrine on the greatness of Mary.**

Comment: You should also point out: One must be in a state of grace and a faithful and practicing Catholic. Otherwise, the prayer loses its effectiveness. You can't give what you don't have...

Comment: @Grasper Your correct,  striving and keeping to live in the state of grace is important.As scriptures said the prayer of a righteous man is powerful. Godbless

Answer (score 0):

**Is it true that anyone who prays the rosary cannot be touched by Satan?**

**Generally speaking it may be true, but it is not absolute.**

Some canonized saints who prayed the Holy Rosary has suffered diabolical attacks and in very rare cases even diabolic possession.

Let me try to explain.

Praying the rosary is a [great sign of predestination](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/54066/25495) for those who pray the rosary with true devotion and love.

There are [Our Lady's 15 Promises for Praying the Rosary](https://www.ourladyswarriors.org/prayer/15promise.htm), but we must recall to ourselves a simple fact:

> These promises mean that, by faithfully and devoutly praying the Rosary, Our Lady will obtain for us the necessary Graces to obtain said promises. It is still up to each individual soul to respond to those Graces in order to obtain salvation.

Until we are in heaven we must keep in mind that Satan and his Demons will always try to make us fall into sin and thus keep us out of heaven.

> **Signs of Predestination**
>
> Can we be certain in this life that we are predestined? In answer to this question the Council of Trent says: "No one, so long as he is in this mortal life, ought so far to presume as regards the secret mystery of divine predestination as to determine for certain that he is assuredly in the number of the predestinate; as if it were true that he who is justified either cannot sin any more, or, if he do sin, that he ought to promise himself an assured repentance. For, except by special revelation, it cannot be known whom God hath chosen unto Himself."14 The reason for this is because, without a special revelation, we cannot know for certain what depends solely upon God's free will. Not one of the just, unless it is specially revealed, knows whether he will persevere in the performance of good works and in prayer. We shall be, says St. Paul, "heirs indeed of God and joint heirs with Christ; yet so, if we suffer [perseveringly] with Him, that we may be also glorified with Him."15
>
> Are there, however, any signs of predestination such as to give one a sort of moral certainty of perseverance? The Fathers, especially John Chrysostom, Augustine, Gregory the Great, Bernard, and Anselm, according to certain statements of Holy Scripture, pointed out several signs of predestination often enumerated by the theologians as follows:
>
> 1.a good life;
>
> 2.the testimony of a conscience that is free from serious sins and prepared rather to die than offend God grievously;
>
> 3.patience in adversities endured for the love of God;
>
> 4.readiness to hear the word of God;
>
> 5.compassion for the poor;
>
> 6.love of one's enemies;
>
> 7.humility;
>
> 8.a special devotion to the Blessed Virgin whom we ask every day to pray for us at the hour of our death.
>
> Among these signs, certain ones, such as Christian patience in adversity, are proof that the inequality of natural conditions is at times more than compensated by divine grace. This is borne out by the beatitudes as recorded in the Gospel: "Blessed are the poor in spirit, the meek, they that mourn, they that hunger and thirst after justice, the merciful, the clean of heart, the peacemakers, they that suffer persecution for justice' sake: for theirs is the kingdom of heaven." These are the predestined. St. Thomas points out especially in his teaching that to bear patiently a heavy cross and for a long time is a sign of predestination. - [What is a special sign of predestination?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/54066/25495)

As I have mentioned above that praying the rosary daily and with devotion will generally protect us from being touched by Satan or his Minions, but it is not absolute. Although we pray the rosary, we must truly pray and strive for holiness. St. Miriam of Jesus Crucified is an example of this. She is not an unique case either.

Even if we do all in our power to strive for perfection, Satan is always at the door try to find a crack to come in.

**If God has permitted the saints to be diabolically possessed, how can we be absolutely sure Satan can not touch us? The saints prayed the rosary. The saints are holy. Yet it happens in rare circumstances.**

[Saint Mariam Baouardy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariam_Baouardy) (St. Mariam of Jesus Crucified) was known for her devotion to the Blessed Virgin Mary and in fact was miraculously cured by Mary herself.

> On 8 September 1858, Mary convinced him she would never abandon her faith; in response he cut her throat and dumped her in an alley. Mary lived, an apparition of the Virgin Mary treated her wound, and she left her uncle’s house forever.
>
> She supported herself as a domestic, working for a Christian family and praying. In 1860 she moved in with the Sisters of Saint Joseph. Supernatural events began to occur around her, and the Sisters would not let her join their house. She was taken to the Carmel at Pau by a Sister in 1867, and became a lay sister. Later that year she entered the cloister, taking the name Mary of Jesus Crucified, and making her final profession on 21 November 1871.
>
> She continued to experience supernatural events. **She fought off a demonic possession for 40 days, received the stigmata, was seen to levitate, had the gift of prophecy and knowledge of consciences, and permitted her guardian angel to speak through her.** Helped found the missionary Carmel of Mangalore, India. Returned to France in 1872. Built a Carmelite monastery in Bethlehem in 1875. Supernatural gifts aside, she was known for her devotion to the Holy Spirit, even sending word to Pope Pius IX that the Spirit was not emphasized enough in seminaries. - [Saint Mary of Jesus Crucified](https://catholicsaints.info/saint-mary-of-jesus-crucified/)

St. Mary of Jesus Crucified was a Carmelite Nun of 19th century and Carmelites are renown for their devotion to [Our Lady and the rosary](http://www.carmelite.org/carmelite-spirituality/prayer-carmel/carmelite-and-popular-marian-prayers) and for the famous [Scapular of Our Lady of Mount Carmel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapular_of_Our_Lady_of_Mount_Carmel).

[image: Our Lady of Mount Carmel statue in Chile with a Brown Scapular]

[Our Lady of Mount Carmel statue in Chile with a Brown Scapular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapular_of_Our_Lady_of_Mount_Carmel)